# Relative path to static css files does not load on a new tab

Tags: reactjs

Hello I have a react app and I set the "homepage": "./" in package.json, this works for me when my application loads from the sub-directory. All the Js and CSS files get relative paths in their href attributes.

Landing page URL: `https//:<my-domain>/<sub-directory-path>`

The problem comes when I click on a link from my landing page it opens the new tab in a browser and the browser tries to load the page but it fails and throws the following error:

```
Refused to apply style from 'https:<my-domain>/<sub-directory-path>/somepage/static/css/8.28838c0e.chunk.css' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled.
```

When I checked in the elements tab of the browser the CSS links are loaded as followed and which is the same in my landing page

```
<link href="./static/css/8.28838c0e.chunk.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

I think because the new tab opened and URL has changed the CSS is trying to load from relative path and that's why the error is coming.

Any idea how to fix this? OR I should not open a new tab when there is relative path set for the homepage key in package.json file?

Answer (score 0):

Try specifying the type of the css file `type="text/css"`
and removing the dot from the css link path `href="static/css/8.28838c0e.chunk.css"`

The html line should look like this:

`<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="static/css/8.28838c0e.chunk.css"/>`

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.